# The meaning of "I never saw you as forgiving"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does it mean the same as "I never thought you were a forgiving person"?

Comment: You're absolutely right, the two sentences mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in your understanding of your sentence meaning

The opposite would be

> You are very **unforgiving**.